# if R is a commutative ring in which all the prime ideals are finitely generated then R is Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Prove that if $R$ is a commutative ring in which all the prime ideals are finitely generated, then $R$ is Noetherian.

Here is what I been told to do: Suppose that $R$ is not Noetherian, and use Zorn’s lemma to obtain a maximal element $I$ in the collection of all ideals of $R$ that are not finitely generated. 
Then use the following proposition: Let $I$ be an ideal of a commutative ring $R$, and let $r ∈ R$. If the ideals $I +rR$ and {$s ∈ R : sr ∈ I$} are finitely generated, then $I$ is a finitely generated ideal.

Can anyone help please. thanks a lot.

Comment: does complete proof help you?

Comment: yes, that would be help a lot. thank you.

Comment: This is sometimes called [Cohen's theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/424638/29335), depending on the context.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Book: *Steps in Commutative Algebra* (by *Sharp*)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is $K=(P:a)$?

Comment: all elements like $r$ that $ra\in P$

Comment: Did you really show p is finitely generated though? P=Rp1+Rp2 +...........+Rpn + aK not Ra?