# Rings in which every maximal ideal is finitely generated

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring with unity in which every maximal ideal is finitely generated. Then is $R$ Noetherian?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183199/commutative-non-noetherian-rings-in-which-all-maximal-ideals-are-finitely-genera     and the answer is no, of course.

Comment: the answer is no. but by addition assumption, "every prime ideal is finitely generated", it will be yes: see for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130223/if-r-is-a-commutative-ring-in-which-all-the-prime-ideals-are-finitely-generated/1130240#1130240)