# submodules $IB$ and $pB$ of finitely generated module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$  is a commutative ring contains $1$, $B$ is a finitely generated A-module.

Here is my conjecture:

> If every prime ideals $p$ of $A$ such that those submodules $pB$ is finitely generated then every ideals $I$ of $A$ , we have submodules $IB$  is finitely generated.

This problem pops in to my head very naturally. But I seem to be stuck in it.

I need some proofs for it if it's true, otherwise, a counterexample.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to construct a counterexample with $B=A$?

Comment: no. I'm not please say more specific.

Comment: Related to the above comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130223/if-r-is-a-commutative-ring-in-which-all-the-prime-ideals-are-finitely-generated

Comment: Cohen's theorem for modules has been proved by Jothilingam as far as I remember, which say that If $M$ is a finitely generated $R$ module, and if $pM$ are finitely generated $R$ modules for every $p\in Spec(R)$, then $M$ is Noetherian.