# if R is a commutative ring in which all the maximal ideals are finitely generated then R is Noetherian?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

It is well known that [if R is a commutative ring in which all the **prime ideals** are finitely generated then R is Noetherian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130223/if-r-is-a-commutative-ring-in-which-all-the-prime-ideals-are-finitely-generated/1130240#1130240).
Is this also true for maximal ideals instead of primes:

if R is a commutative ring in which all the **maximal ideals** are finitely generated then is R  Noetherian?

Comment: @user 1 ,,,,,,,